# Plan bootstrap to React-Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

How can I write the next snippet of plain bootstrap to react-bootstrap?

My main problem is how to translate this part `class="nav-item dropdown"`, because both classes exist as react-bootstrap elements

```html
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle userInfo" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" 
    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="far fa-user-circle"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: It is literally in the docs mate -> https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns

Did you try something by yourself?

Comment: Thanks @PrateekThapa, yes you're right it was in the documentation but more precisely in this link [https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/#using-dropdowns]

Answer (score 1):

Bro, First of all you need to learn how to add router from react. Because, i saw some links. So, In React, you must use router like context, react-router-dom etc. In React-bootstrap, for example

```
<div class = "container"></div> in react bootstrap => <Container></Container>
```

You muust do also install react-bootstrap with yarn or npm

Second request in use react, you may use className instead of class.

Finally, These are react-bootstrap navbar:

```
<Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
  <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className="mr-auto">
      <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
      <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Divider />
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
      </NavDropdown>
    </Nav>
    <Form inline>
      <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
      <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
    </Form>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

You can use this navbar.

Take Care...